# Building QGIS 2.8.6 on Win 7 32bit?

Tags: qgis, python, windows-7, compile

I'm trying to build QGIS 2.8.6 on Windows 7 32 bit using MSVC Express 10. The build process completes without errors, but with a bunch of warnings. When I run the qgis.exe after installation, it only shows the splash screen for a few seconds until "Starting python" appears. Then it vanishes and nothing happens.

When building python_module_qgis__gui in MSVC Express I get the following warnings. I get similar ones when building python_module_qgis_core and python_module_gis_analysis.

> Generating gui/sip_guipart0.cpp, gui/sip_guipart1.cpp,
> gui/sip_guipart2.cpp, gui/sip_guipart3.cpp    sip_guipart0.cpp
> c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\math.h(162):
> warning C4211: Nonstandard extension used : redefined extern to static
> sip_guipart1.cpp c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 10.0\VC\include\math.h(162): warning C4211: Nonstandard extension used : redefined extern to static
>
> sip_guipart2.cpp c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
> 10.0\VC\include\math.h(162): warning C4211: Nonstandard extension used : redefined extern to static   sip_guipart3.cpp c:\Program
> Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\math.h(162): warning
> C4211: Nonstandard extension used : redefined extern to static
> Looks like there might be a problem with Python and SIP?

My cmake configuration is this:

> Found PostgreSQL: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/libpq.lib
>
> Found SpatiaLite: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/spatialite_i.lib
>
> Found Qt version: 4.8.6
>
> Touch support disabled
>
> Found QScintilla2: C:/OSGeo4W/lib/qscintilla2.lib (2.8.4)
>
> Found Python executable: C:/OSGeo4W/bin/python.exe
>
> Found Python version: 2.7.4
>
> Found Python library: C:/OSGeo4W/apps/Python27/libs/python27.lib
>
> Found SIP version: 4.16.5
>
> Found PyQt4 version: 4.11.3
>
> Found QScintilla2 PyQt4 module: 2.8.4

Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong?

Comment: While *using* GIS software is a GIS SE topic, ***compiling*** it is more a software development issue, and therefore more appropriate to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I figured it out by myself. The warning were not the problem. SIP was installed for the wrong platform (msvc 2008). So I reinstalled SIP for msvc 2010, reinstalled PyQt and it worked.